# How many parameters of a RL environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proximal-policy-optimization, intelligent-agent, environment

I’m working at a Reinforcement Learning model, using PPO algorithm, in which the agent has 4 possible actions, acting in a stochastic  environment defined by 3 parameters. 
Given its stochasticity, I was thinking it would be better to store also the parameters of the previous step, ending up in 6 parameters. 
My question is: when these parameters are too many? If I store the previous 5 results, I end up with 5*3=15 parameters, thus it could be more complicated to reach a local maximum.
When do you think I should stop? What’s the reasoning behind it?